# Simple Cases of hadamard product

Tags: generating-functions

I have a simple recursive formula $a_{n+1} = (1+ 1/n) a_n +1$ and try to find the generating function of ${a^2_n}$. A classic approach is using Hadamard product of the generating function of A(x) with itself. However it leads to complex integrals. Is there any algebraic way to find ${a^2_n}$ recursively and then compute its generating functions directly as for the Fibonacci sequence. I tried but can not find a way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this for $n \ge 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}$$
Hence, by the telescopic sum we obtain:
$$\frac{a_n}{n}=a_1+H_n-1$$ or
$$a_n^2=\left(na_1+n\left(H_n-1\right)\right)^2,$$
where $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: How it relates to a recursion for $a^2_n$, Please advise.

Comment: @Rasoul I fixed. See now, please.

Comment: Thanks, what happens if $a_{n+1} = (1+ {a_0}/n) a_n +1$, Is there any general approach?

Comment: @Rasoul It seems hard. I think.